# GCC 4.8.0 build size differ greatly on OS X and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-construction

Immediately after GCC 4.8.0 was released, I built it on OS X 10.8 with ISL and CLooG. The complete build was about 3.8 GB in size (release tar balls + untarred sources + all generated objects). I couldn't remember which compiler I used for that build. I guess GCC does not pick up Apple clang? Then probably the compiler was the default GCC 4.2.1 `/usr/bin`; all other versions of GCC were installed elsewhere, and I'm sure I didn't customize `CC`.

Today I built GCC 4.8.0 again on Ubuntu 12.04, this time without ISL and CLooG. The complete build was about 5.3 GB in size (still release tar balls + untarred sources + all generated objects). The compiler for this build was GCC 4.7.3.

This is rather interesting. Why are the sizes so much different? Does this indicate that Mach-O is more space-efficient than ELF? Or are there other factors?

Comment: GCC is usually self-compiling in stages 2 or 3.....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Okay, then why the size difference?

Answer (score 0):

Is one 64-bit only and the other 32-bit and 64-bit?

If you want to compare Mach-O vs. ELF, you probably need to grab a couple representative files from both builds.

Comment: For the 64-bit thing, no. I didn't give any architecture config option. Actually x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0 and x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu both base on the same hardware—the gnu/linux one is my Ubuntu virtual machine.

Comment: For the representative files, `gcc-4.8.0` 1.0M (Darwin) vs 3.0M (Linux), `g++-4.8.0` 1.0M vs 3.0M, `gcj-4.8.0 1.0M` vs 3.1M, etc, `gfortran-4.8.0` 1.0M vs 3.0M. A very good pattern here. But something like `aot-compile-4.8.0`, which I don't actually know what it is, is 3.0K vs 3.1K.

Comment: Mach-O is known to not include debug section, right? But the debug info should lie somewhere in the build, I suppose (otherwise `gdb` won't work). I tried to `readelf` but couldn't see anything interesting. On the other hand, I never tried `otool`, so I didn't bother to read Mach-O.